# Identifying the remapped function in a CodeIgniter controller

Tags: codeigniter, remap

My controller has a remap function that redirects routed calls for its index method to either methodA or methodB.

From within each of these two methods, an external class instance makes a call to it's own methods, something like this:

```
methodA(){

$newClass = new newClass();

$newClass->doStuff();

}
```

in doStuff(), the code does stuff contingent to what segment was referenced. Essentially, I may get data like this

doStuff(){
       $data =  $assets[$this->ci->router->fetch_class()][$this->ci->router->fetch_method()];
}

But this will fail since $this->ci->router->fetch_method() will return index, not the remapped method. I need to be able to retrieve the remapped method for the correct data corresponding to the remapped method.

I can easily do this by passing the name of the invoking function to this method call, but is there a more CodeIgniter way of doing this ? i.e: Getting the remapped method to which the router method was mapped onto ?

If not, alternate solutions ?

Comment: I feel fairly sure that the "best" way to solve this is go go back a bit further and figure out how to *not* have `newClass` rely on which controller method it was called from. Also `_remap` is rarely necessary, sounds like the code might be a little convoluted in general.

Comment: I agree. But this class is used for dynamically loading assets belonging to a specific codeIgniter controller/method combination. Essentially, what javascripts belong to a specific webpage. Not sure if there is any other way of doing this